# Step to cursor/line eclipse debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Is there a possibility to step to any following line while debugging in eclipse?

It will help debug situations when I have a breakpoint at method beginning, I check something there, and below there is a for loop that i want to step through fast to see all changes it made at once.

Currently in the above scenario I put a breakpoint below the for-loop, hit F8, remove the breakpoint after execution stops which is pretty cumbersome.

Is there a better method of doing above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Put break point at start of function.
2. Check XYZ. Come up to for loop.
3. Put your cursor after for loop.
4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
5. **HURRAY!!!!!** I skiped for loop in debug.

Comment: Here is a nice pictorial blog on the steps.  http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19356.html